# Extract the last occurence of a string that changes dynamically

Tags: string, bash, sed

I need to extract and set to a variable only the last numeric value that appears once or more in text like the following:

```
The http port is 4060
```

So in order to retrieve only the value of `4060` I concluded in the following `sed` command:

```
sed -n -e "s/The http port is \([0-9]*\)/\1/p" file.txt
```

However since this port value may appear more than once and with different values each time,
I need each time to extract only the last occurrence of the numeric value and I haven't found a way to do that in combination with the above sed command

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily with `awk`

```
awk '/The http port is/ {f=$NF} END {print f}' file
```

It will search for `The http port is`, and if found store it in variable  `f`.
When its done going trough the file, it will print the `f`, and it will always have the last found data.

---

If data is on different location within the line, you can do:

```
awk -F"The http port is " '{f=$2+0} END {print f}' file
```

Comment: It worked great. Thanks a lot for your help. I really should check awk too.

Comment: Another variation if you're using GNU awk and that text appears dynamically by position: `awk 'match($0, /The http port is ([0-9]+)/, a){ f = a[1] } END { print f }' file`

Comment: @sisyphus1979 You should accept it if it's the correct answer for you.

Comment: @konsolebox If you need a dynamically position non `gnu awk` solution, see my updated post.

Comment: @sisyphus1979 Click on the white check mark to the left of the post.  If you have no right to do it, click the up arrow to give +1

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n -e "s/The http port is \([0-9]*\)/\1/p" file.txt | tail -n 1
```

Comment: Regarding the command tail doesn't is need a file in its syntax? with pipeline and no file as an input doesn't work for me. I need to say that a I'm not quite familiar with the unix commands yet.

Comment: No, tail does not need a filename. It's completely normal to use it in a pipeline. But the sed command was wrong, I copied it blindly from the question without testing it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` with look-behind:

```
grep -oP '(?<=The http port is )[0-9]+' file | tail -n 1
```

With it the phrase may appear anywhere in the file even between strings.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/The http port is \([0-9]*\)/h;$!d;x;s//\1/g' file
```

This saves the last line containing the instance of the http port in the hold space and at end-of-file swaps to it and retrieves the number.